# Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month

Tags: excel

I have excel data in following format.

```
Date        Amount

03-Jan-13   430.00 
25-Jan-13   96.00 
10-Jan-13   440.00 
28-Feb-13   72.10 
28-Feb-13   72.30
```

I need to sum the amount field only if the month lies in **Jan** Month.

What i have tried is ,

```
=SUMIF(A2:A6,"MONTH(A2:A6)=1",B2:B6)
```

But it returns,

```
0
```

What i need is,

```
Following values to be summed, 430.00 + 96.00 + 440.00 = 966.00
```

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/75814-sum-if-date-month.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
  =SUM(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=1,$B$2:$B$6,0))
```

It's an array formula, so you will need to enter it with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Here's how the formula works.

1. MONTH($A$2:$A$6) creates an array of numeric values of the month for the dates in A2:A6, that is, 
    `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2}`.
2. Then the comparison `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2}= 1` produces the array `{TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE}`, which comprises the condition for the IF statement.
3. The IF statement then returns an array of values, with `{430, 96, 400..` for the values of the sum ranges where the month value equals 1 and `..0,0}` where the month value does not equal 1.
4. That array `{430, 96, 400, 0, 0}` is then summed to get the answer you are looking for.

This is essentially equivalent to what the SUMIF and SUMIFs functions do. However, neither of those functions support the kind of calculation you tried to include in the conditional.

It's also possible to drop the IF completely.  Since TRUE and FALSE can also be treated as 1 and 0,  this formula--`=SUM((MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=1)*$B$2:$B$6)`--also works.

*Heads up: This does not work in Google Spreadsheets*

Comment: Thanks it works.. Could you please let me know how this array works ?

Comment: Is there a way to specify a full column? Something like MONTH(A:A)? I ended up needing to pick a large number since my excel sheet is constantly added to (I am also referencing a different sheet). `=SUM(IF(MONTH(Input!$A$2:$A$10000)=11,Input!$E$2:$E$10000,0))`

Answer (score 26):

```
=Sumifs(B:B,A:A,">=1/1/2013",A:A,"<=1/31/2013")
```

The beauty of this formula is you can add more data to columns A and B and it will just recalculate.

Comment: It is an excellent formula, provided you only want to check for January in the **year 2013**.  Although that may be the OP's desire, he did not mention year specificity in his question.

Comment: For those in UK, remember to switch the 31 and 1 around... that caught me out.

Answer (score 19):

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=1) * ($B$2:$B$6) )
```

Explanation:

- `(MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=1)` creates an array of 1 and 0, it's 1 when the
  month is january, thus in your example the returned array would be `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`
- `SUMPRODUCT` first multiplies each value of the array created in the above step with values of the array `($B$2:$B$6)`, then it sums them. Hence in
  your example it does this: `(1 * 430) + (1 * 96) + (1 * 440) + (0 * 72.10) + (0 * 72.30)`

*This works also in OpenOffice and Google Spreadsheets*