# how to make a <<sum(if()) array formula with multiple conditions>>

Tags: excel

My question is basically the same as this one : [Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month)

But the difference is that my table contains one more information (from where the money has been spent, groceries for example), and I want to be able to have a formula that tells me, how much I have spent at place y in month x. Example, How much did I spent at Costco in January. I have tried to adapt the formula from the other post ([Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month)) by adding an AND to the IF formula, but it doesn't work.

What are you suggestions?

(The reason I didn't post my actually Excel sheet is that I don't know how to post it and keep the format)

Comment: It looks like you may be better served by creating a [Pivot Table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx)

Comment: AND doesn't work as required in array formulas because it returns a single value (TRUE or FALSE) rather than the required array of values - you can use * (multiply) to simulate AND or use multiple IFs......but there are better ways with SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT (or non-formula approaches like pivot table as suggested), see below

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about Excel formulas and I think it should be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

*in your case:*

**`=SUMIFS(sum_range, range_of_places_where_you_search, cell_with_place_name_you_need_sum_for, range_of_month_where_you_search, cell_with_month_name_you_need_to_sum_for)`**

*dont forget about `=month()` & `=year()` formulas which take moth and year from date
combining which like this `=year()&month()` you can look for total spendings per month*

[SUMIFS function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Adds the cells in a range that meet multiple criteria. For example, if you want to sum the numbers in the range A1:A20 only if the corresponding numbers in B1:B20 are greater than zero (0) and the corresponding numbers in C1:C20 are less than 10, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A20, B1:B20, ">0", C1:C20, "<10")
```

Important   The order of arguments differ between the SUMIFS and SUMIF functions. In particular, the sum_range argument is the first argument in SUMIFS, but it is the third argument in SUMIF. If you are copying and editing these similar functions, make sure you put the arguments in the correct order.
Syntax

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2,
         criteria2], …)
```

The SUMIFS function syntax has the following arguments:

`sum_range`
Required. One or more cells to sum, including numbers or names, ranges, or cell references that contain numbers. Blank and text values are ignored.

`criteria_range1`
Required. The first range in which to evaluate the associated criteria.

`criteria1`
Required. The criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells in the criteria_range1 argument will be added. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, ">32", B4, "apples", or "32."

`criteria_range2`, `criteria2`, …
Optional. Additional ranges and their associated criteria. Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As Igor suggests you can use `SUMIFS` if you have Excel 2007 or later version. SUMIFS will be more efficient than using array formulas or `SUMPRODUCT` in general.

If you have Dates in column A, Places in B and Amount spent in C then if you put the 1st of the relevant month in E2 (e.g. 1-May-2013, you can format the cell to display just month and year like May-2013) then use this formula in F2

`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">="&$E2,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH($E2,0)+1,B:B,F$1)`

where F1 contains a specific place like Costco

Now you can add more dates in `E3` down and more places in `G1` across and formula can be copied down and across to get a table of totals for a range of places across a range of dates

Also see this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/601389/sumif-by-category-and-date-in-range) at Superuser - Scott's answer is very similar to my suggested solution here