# Excel sum days by month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet #1: Daily Data

Column A: Days in format dd/mm/yyyy
Column B: Quantity

Sheet #2: Quantity by Month

Column A: Months in format mm/yy
Column B: Summed Quantity

I tried using:

```
=SUMIFS('Daily Data'!E17:E600,'Daily Data'!A17:A600,"=??/01/2013")
```

this does not work

tired using:

```
 =SUMIFS('Daily Data'!E17:E600,'Daily Data'!A17:A600,"=??/"&MONTH(A1)&"/2013")
```

nope, doesn't work

Tried if with asterix and it does not work either

Anyone can help out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Daily Data'!E17:E600)*(MONTH('Daily Data'!A17:A600)=MONTH(A1)))
```

but if you have dates from different years in `'Daily Data'!A17:A600` you should adjust formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Daily Data'!E17:E600)*(MONTH('Daily Data'!A17:A600)=MONTH(A1))*(YEAR('Daily Data'!A17:A600)=YEAR(A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=Sumifs('Daily Data'!E17:E600,'Daily Data'!A17:A600,">=1/1/2013",'Daily Data'!A17:A600,"<=1/31/2013")
```

If you want to be able to enter a date in `A1` and use that you would use:

```
=SUMIFS('Daily Data'!E17:E600,'Daily Data'!A17:A600,">"&EOMONTH(A1,-1),'Daily Data'!A17:A600,"<="&EOMONTH(A1,0))
```