# Excel SUMIF Date falls within a date period (fiscal year)

Tags: excel, date, excel-2003

I have been using the formula

=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=1,$B$2:$B$6,0))

Featured in this question..

[Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month/23396765#23396765)

To calculate the the sum in a calender year, by changing Month to Year in the formula.

What i now need to do is Sum the amount  in a financial year April to April rather than the calender year.

So with the data set something like

```
01/02/2013  2
13/03/2013  3
06/06/2013  4   *
09/11/2013  5   *
31/01/2014  6   *
28/03/2014  7   *
16/04/2014  10
```

And the financial year 01/04/2013 - 31/03/14

I would be looking to sum up the asterisk values ending up with 22.

I am happy to have the start and end dates as cell values.

Its been a long time since I have played with excel and I am very rusty!

As this sheet is used across various networked machines and various excel versions i am keen to avoid macros.

I have tried a few things which are abject failures and i will not bore you with.

TIA

Tom

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? (Writing more to reach 30 characters)

[image]

For Excel versions < 2007:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a go on a Excel 2007 + machine at work.

I should have said earlier I am running Excel XP/2003 so do not have access to SUMIFS

Comment: Your welcome! The amended response also works for pre 2007 versions.