# Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular range of dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula, date-range

What I'm trying to do is create an excel file that our company's stores can use to track newspaper returns and sales.

We then further use this file here at the HQ for reconciling the invoices on a monthly basis when they are sent to us.

ThE tables I'm using have the following data:

```
   A      B        C                  D
```

1)  07/30.....$1.90.....FORMULA

2)  07/31.....$1.60.....FORMULA

3)  08/01.....$2.10.....FORMULA

4)  08/02.....$5.60.....FORMULA

5)  08/03.....$4.70.....FORMULA...... WEEKLY TOTAL(=SUM(B2:B?)

ETC ETC ETC ETC

In this example, my store managers simply track received papers and returned papers which are then totaled by cost to give the data (extended cost) in column B. The excel file is simply an ongoing, never ending list of values that are simply organized by date in the form of weekly blocks, which subtotal each week in column D. My managers need this column for weekly totals, as the weeks don't necessary coincide nicely. (i.e. you may have totals from August and September in 1 week's block)

I'm using the following formula to calculate monthly totals in a hidden column E (these are calendar month totals that run from the 1st of the month to the 31st of the month so its easy to do):

- FORMULA

=IF(MONTH(C5)<>MONTH(C5+1),SUM(H$5:H5)-SUMIF(C$5:C5,"<"&DATE(YEAR(C5),MONTH(C5),1),H$5:H5),"")

That works great, as it basically gives me a running total for the calendar month of the 1ST through the end of the month. It also eliminates all previous monthly bills using the SUMIF formula toward the end of the formula. The problem that I'm having is trying to recreate this with another newspaper that does not run on a set calendar month. The invoice, instead, is billed for the 16th of a month through the 15th of the next month.

The invoices for this other paper typically start on the 16th of a month and end on the 15th of the following month. So what I need is a formula (hopefully as similar to the one I mentioned using earlier so that I can understand how it works) that will sum for a given date range (i.e. 06/16/14 - 07/15/14) that won't show any from outside of that date range, even though the data is a giant list.

I wish that I could post images (need at least 10 reputation) as this would make this explanation 10 times easier, but it won't allow me to do so.

Comment: That would be fine if I were looking for historical data, or wanted to complete the work myself, but I'm looking for a working formula that would simply respond to my managers inputting data into their spreadsheets. I need a formula that could do the same as stated above for a date range rather than for a 1st of the month through end of the month range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should just be able to use SUMIFS to set multiple conditions for your date column. I assume C is your date column while H is your daily sales column.

=IF(DAY($C5)<>15,"",SUMIFS($H:$H,$C:$C,"<="&DATE(YEAR($C5),MONTH($C5),15),$C:$C,">="&DATE(YEAR($C5),MONTH($C5)-1,16)))

The above formula will add all values from the 16th of the previous month up to and including the 15th of the current month. Cells where the day does not equal 15 will be blank.

I tested this on a blank worksheet with about a year's worth of sequential dates in column C and random currency values in column H, with this formula in every cell in column I. So it should work for your purposes unless there's a piece of the puzzle I'm missing, so to speak. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm curious to how this formula works. I'm so-so when it comes to arrays and using the SUMIF formula, but I've never had to use the SUMIFS formula prior to just now. I see the brilliance here is in the section of the formula referencing "MONTH($C5)-1,16. Not 100% sure how this works, especially since I didn't even have to define the start array at H$5:h5, etc. But it did work :)

Comment: Basically every instance of this formula is searching the entire H column every time. But the conditions of the SUMIFS use whatever date is in the H cell next to it to narrow the search to any date that is between the 16th of the previous month and the 15th of the current month. You can use the entire columns as arrays because 0 values or text values won't ever exist between any two dates, so you don't have to worry about excluding your header row (though you can if you want). This also means you can sort the data by something other than date without the monthly amounts getting screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed this from here([Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month)) and is an easy formula to use:

```
=Sumifs(B:B,A:A,">=1/1/2013",A:A,"<=1/31/2013")
```

you sum column B, for the total value
then set two parameters, one at the beginnig of the date you wish to use, and one at the end dat, inclusive.
The example used here is for the whole month of January.

I tried linking it to a cell with said dates but it didnt work, although maybe someone knows how to get around that. So for now, type in the dates you wish to use in the formula