# Excel If command to see if a date falls between a date range excluding the year

Tags: excel

If I have a date of birth e.g. 1/1/1990, I need to see if this date of birth falls between a date range when when this person stays with me e.g. 12/12/2022 to 02/03/2023. In this example it's Yes.

I've tired this formula but it includes the year

```
=IF(AND(H4>V4,H4<AA4),"Yes", "No")
```

where H4 is DOB, V4 is arrival and AA4 is departure.

Any help would  be great,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000698/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-range-of-dates)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact functions, but you might opt for this approach:

Take the person't birthday, retrieve day and month and make from that a new date. Do the same with the beginning and ending day and verify if the adapted birthday is between the adapted beginning and ending day.

**Edit:** example:

```
Cell C1=DATE(0, MONTH(Birthday),  DAY(Birthday))
Cell C2=DATE(0, MONTH(Beginning), DAY(Beginning))
Cell C3=DATE(0, MONTH(Ending),    DAY(Ending))
```

Result:

```
=AND(C3>=C1,C2<=C1)
```

Comment: Sir, as per your solution then a `DAY()` Function should be used right?

Comment: `Day()` and `Month()` functions are needed for retrieving day and month number, indeed.

Comment: @Dominique Thanks for the super prompt reply. It kind of works, if all the dates are in the same year e.g. DOB 30/09 - Arrival 03/09, Depart 17/12 Then Yes it is perfect. However if DOB is 31/01 - Arrival 03/09, Depart 29/02 (following year) then it doesn't work. Any workaround for this part do you think?

Comment: I have solved my problem a different way. I created a formula to work out when the persons next birthday will be. Then I can use my original formula and it works fine :)

Comment: @AlexBrown Sir, it would be nice if you share your solution as well, in the same thread or in Answer. that will helps others in the future.!

Answer (score 1):

I approached this slightly differently and it did mean I added a new column to my Spreadheet.
This was Next Birthday. The formula is:

```
=IF(H3<>"",EDATE(H3,(DATEDIF(H3,$I$1,"y")+1)*12),"")
```

H3  Date of Birth
I1 A Preset Date, for me it is 1st Sept of this year,as this is when School Starts

Then the Formula to see if the student would have a birthday when they were with me was:

```
=IF(AND(AH3>V3,AH3<AA3),"Yes", "No")
```

AH3  my new column "Next Birthday"
V3  Arrival Date
AA3  Departure Date

I then simply used some conditional formatting to change those with a Yes to a bold color to be able to see them easily
[image]