# Sum on a specific day obeying a status

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that applies the following format:

```
   Date    Value    Situation
01/01/2015  $100     Expected
01/01/2015  $150     Paid - Cash
01/02/2015  $100     Expected
01/06/2015  $200     Paid - Credit card
```

Where I update the status by a dropdown menu as the values become real.

And I also have a database which has day and value cells. I found around here a way to sum the values per day (btw, [thank you logan and chuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month)). But I'm having headaches to sum the values obeying the dates AND ALSO the status.

In the database where there are cells indicating the day and values, I have the following formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(AND((DAY(IncomeJan[Date])=DAY(A1));IncomeJan[Status]<>"Expected");IncomeJan[Value];0))}
```

And it returns the value 0.

I need to sum only real values. And to avoid creating multiple IFs to specify the payment method, I would like to sum only the values that follow a specific day and contains in status the word 'Paid'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @pnuts sorry for not being clear. what I mean to the values 'become real' is because I created this worksheet to make a financial tracking in a company, which works with real values. the 'unreal' for me is when I have a revenue forecast, but this money hasn't been deposited in the bank account. I want to get all entries for a specific day that meet the status "Paid" and sum them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"=*Paid*")
```

meets the requirement to "I want to get all entries for a specific day that meet the status "Paid" and sum them".

Available for Excel 2007 and later, the [SUMIFS](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c59af066-13c2-47da-afe8-49c81ab233fb?CorrelationId=a2a289a4-53fd-4993-8292-ebc59cb6394e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) syntax is:

> SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)

The *sum_range*, switched to be the first parameter rather than the last for SUMIF, is the `Value` column (here assumed to be ColumnB), one criteria range (*criteria_range1*) is `Date`(so assumed to be ColumnA) with `A2` (*criteria1*) taken as an example of the required specific date (assumed to be `01/01/2015` = in part because not clear from the question whether the date examples are US style or UK style, though likely US), one additional criterion range (there could be more) is (*criteria_range2*) that the`Situation` column (assumed to be ColumnC) contains `Paid`.  This last criterion (*criteria2*) wraps `Paid` in wildcards (`*`) so that it triggers wherever `Paid` may be found in any one `Situation` cell, even if there surrounded by other text.

Based on the sample, the above formula returns $150 since that is the only entry shown as `Paid` on 01/01/2015 but would return $350 were the date of the last entry in the sample changed to `01/01/2015`.

The `Dates` need not be date/time indexes (numeric) but could be strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This formula returns zero, I realized that the problem is when the formula attempts to identify the date. When specifying it (such as 01/06/2015 and not just the day 6), it works perfectly. Here is a database image and an example of the table that I use to add entries: http://i.imgur.com/t2z4LiK.png

Comment: the formula returns zero when the date is only the day. when the date is "mm/dd/yyyy" format, the formula works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sumproducts as an array forumla you can sum based on multiple If statements.

```
=sumproducts(IF(x1:x10=y,1,0),z1:z10)
```

So if the IF is not meet the z value is timed by 0, therefore equals 0, otherwise by 1 and the Z value will be evaluated; You can add additional IF. So can have a If for date and a if for "paid".

Comment: In order to search for paid you can use  IF(IFERROR(FIND("Paid",x1:x10),0)>0,1,0)