# Sumif Amounts Based on Months for Multiple Months

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have excel data in the following format

```
Date         Amount
01-Jan-16     23.94
12-Jan-16     17.96
26-Jan-16     32.92
03-Feb-16     38.90
20-Feb-16     62.27
26-Feb-16     45.89
```

I would like to sum the amount field for specific months, that is I would like to sum up the amount in January and also in February separately.

This is the code I have tried thus far which I found in a previously asked question (see [Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month)).

`=SUM(IF(MONTH(A:A)=1,B:B,0))`

It works for January but when I change 1 to 2 it returns zero.

`=SUM(IF(MONTH(A:A)=2,B:B,0))`

Would `sumifs` work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two other ways of doing it:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A10)=1)*B2:B10)
```

and

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),A2:A10,"<"&DATE(2016,2,1))
```

Change as necessary to get totals for other months.

I have put the results next to the original array formula in this screen shot:-

[image]

Comment: thank you, this looks like it will work. I ended up deciding to use pivot tables in Excel and I got the correct result but I will try your method as well.

Comment: is there a way to sum across the rows without writing the sums in a different table? What I'm looking for is one last column in my pivot table with the grand totals of the rows written inside my pivot table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - normally a pivot table gives you row and column totals?

Comment: I'm only able to get get grandtotals at the bottom of the pivot table. I would like monthly totals.

Comment: It's true that you don't get row totals if you're showing several different variables in the pivot table. This might help a bit http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/731971-pivot-grand-total-rows-not-showing.html but it might need a separate question with some screenshots to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use specific range rather than full column. You must use the formula as array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$1000)=1,$B$2:$B$1000,0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as array formula.

Comment: That seems a bit redundant. I'm asking excel to search for days with the appropriate month. But in your code I already know the dates I want to sum. I should just use sum(x:x)

Comment: I am confused. Can you please explain little more.

Comment: Yes. I need to sum the cells in the column that are in the rows Jan. I use the formula I provided and it works, but not of I switch 1 to 2. I don't want to grab the rows under amount corresponding to January because I want excel to find them for me first, then sum them together. Using your formula removes the part where I want excel to find the right cells so I don't have to.

Comment: Do you want separate values (Corresponding to Jan, Feb etc) first to another column, then sum?

Comment: The answer is correct - you need to enter it as an array formula and use a range which doesn't include the header A1. But you can also use SUMIFS as described in the original answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month if you are only interested in January/February 2016.

Comment: Tom, maybe I'm confused now but I thought I tried that earlier and it didn't work. Maybe I included the headers, so I'll check if excluding them helps. I'm also interested in using future months.

Comment: @TomSharpe I tried to do it where I did not include the headers, and it only works for the first number I assign (for January in the small subset of the data I included in the original post) but it still does not work for any other months.