# Excel SUMIF for dates within a certain month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My question is directly related to [Excel Formula to SUMIF date falls in particular month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285381/excel-formula-to-sumif-date-falls-in-particular-month), but I can't get my formula to work based on the answers there.

My very simple worksheet looks like this:

```
MONTH        INCOME 
January      {formula goes here and in subsequent rows}
February    
March       
April       
May     
{&c. for all 12 months}
```

I'm trying to get a sum of values in column E from another sheet, called "Worklog", calculating the income total per month.

The “Worklog” sheet is formatted like so:

```
(A)         (B)             (C)             (D)         (E)
DATE        EMPLOYER        DESCRIPTION     AMNT DUE    AMNT REC'D
01/01/17    Employer Name   Project Name    $100         $100 
02/09/17    Employer Name   Project Name    $100         $300 
03/11/17    Employer Name   Project Name    $100         $100 
04/12/17    Employer Name   Project Name    $100         $100 
07/16/17    Employer Name   Project Name    $200         $200
```

I've tried the following, all as array formulas (by entering the formula and hitting Control-Shift-Enter as instructed in the other post):

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (MONTH(Worklog!$A$2:$A$250)=MONTH(A2)) * (Worklog!$E$2:$E$250)
```

and

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(Worklog!$A$2:$A$250)=MONTH(A2),Worklog!$E$2:$E$250,0))
=SUM(IF(MONTH(Worklog!$A$2:$A$250)=1,Worklog!$E$2:$E$250,0))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (MONTH(Worklog!$A$2:$A$250)=1) * (Worklog!$E$2:$E$250) )
```

Although the Date columns are formatted differently (“mmmm” vs “dd/mm/yy”), they are both Date type columns.
The Worklog does contain data for all twelve months.

Where am I going wrong?

I’m running Microsoft Excel for Mac (Version 15.33), in case that makes any difference in how the formulas are written.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(Worklog!$E:$E,Worklog!$A:$A,">=" & EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1,Worklog!$A:$A,"<" & EOMONTH(A2,0)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That works perfectly. It seems really weird to me that the simpler "MONTH" function won't work here, though.... If you can spare another moment, could you possibly help me understand why that is?

Comment: Ah... is it because you can't apply the MONTH function (or any other function of that sort) to a range of cells?